# Excluding arguments from targets of a makefile

Tags: makefile

I try to write a Makefile that is able to filter the arguments it gets to either call a submakefile, or call a specific rule of a submakefile.

It is quite hard to explain what I mean so here is the context:

I have different folders, containing each one tex file and one makefile to build it. In the root folder, I also have a Makefile, which is meant to call the right submakefile depending on its arguments.
I want to split the arguments given to that makefile in 2 categories: either target names or subfolder names and then either call the subfolder's makefile with the given target(s) or call all submakefiles with target(s) if no subfolder provided.

Examples:

`make`: Call all subfolder makefiles default targets.

`make clean`: Call all subfolders makefiles clean targets.

`make tutorial0`: Call the default target of the tutorial0 folder's makefile

`make tutorial0 tutorial1 build chrome-open`: Call the build and chrome-open targets of the tutorial0 and tutorial1 folders.

I came out with a makefile that is calling itself after parsing its own arguments but it does not work quite as intended.

Here is what I've done:

```makefile
CUR_MAKEFILE = $(firstword ${MAKEFILE_LIST})

SUBJECTS = tutorial0 \
           tutorial1

TARGETS = all build clean chrome-open

GOALS = ${filter-out ${SUBJECTS},${MAKECMDGOALS}}
SUBMAKEFILE = ${filter ${SUBJECTS}, ${MAKECMDGOALS}}

# If shell call, then split arguments into makefiles and targets then re-call make with variables
ifndef INTERNAL

${TARGETS}: all

${SUBJECTS}: all

all:
    ${MAKE} -f ${CUR_MAKEFILE} ${SUBMAKEFILE} MAKECMDGOAL=${GOALS} INTERNAL=true

endif

# Else call the right Makefile with the right targets
ifdef INTERNAL

${SUBJECTS}:
    ${MAKE} -C $@ ${MAKECMDGOAL}

${TARGETS}: ${SUBJECTS}

endif

.PHONY: ${TARGETS} ${SUBJECTS}
```

Currently, the SUBJECTS variable contain all the sub-folders names and the TARGETS variable all the possible variables. If the makefile is called without the INTERNAL variable set, it assumes it is called from shell, parses its arguments and self-call with new variables.

What currently happens is the makefile exits after one sub-folder call regardless of the arguments.

I know it is quite ugly but I couldn't find a better way of doing it.

Comment: You cannot control the command line of `make`.  Make is not a general purpose language like shell or Python or whatever, where you can do whatever you want with the command line: it parses its own command line and uses it for its own purposes.  IMO attempts to force it to work differently only lead to frustration.  If you want a very different front-end I recommend you write a little shell script that parses the arguments and invokes make, then call that instead of make directly.

Comment: If you want a solution that is easy to use the "make way" you need to change the command line to use variables as the "build this in subdirectories" targets, like: `make tutorial0 tutorial1 TARGETS="build chrome-open"`

Comment: Okay, I was afraid of this answer. I will stick with that.

Comment: Actually I got this to work properly. This is hacky and quite ugly but it works as I expected: The only thing I was missing was a default rule in the ```ifdef INTERNAL``` part that can call all ${SUBJECTS} rules.